# Test if one of two macros not empty

Tags: conditionals

I define two new macros and commands to change their content with the following commands in a `.cls`-file.

```
\newcommand{\@mymacroa}{}
\newcommand{\mymacroa}[1]{\renewcommand{\@mymacroa}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@mymacrob}{}
\newcommand{\mymacrob}[1]{\renewcommand{\@mymacrob}{#1}}
```

Now I want to test whether one (or both) of these is non-empty (i.e. has been modified from the default value) and if one of these has content, print their values. My previous attempts using `\ifthenelse`, `\@ifnotmtarg` and plain TeX `\if` have not been successful.

In pseudo-code, what I want to achieve is:

```
\@ifnotmtarg{\@mymacroa}\or\@ifnotmtarg{\@mymacrob} 
do {print some text and the macros which are non-empty}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. Also, rather than posting snippets of code can you please expand this to a compliable [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: It might be better to say what you are actually trying to achieve as this seems to be a rather convoluted approach. In similar situations I have used either `\providecommand` to set a default value for a command or document class options to set defaults that can be easily changed. If I really wanted to do something like this then I would use a "binary counter" and then test for values of `0` (nothing set), `1` or `10` (one set) and `11` (both set).

Comment: @Andrew What I want is designing a class file as a complement to a genealogytree. This class is meant to produce a pdf with a persons picture, their place and date of birth (and death respectively) in a tabular followed by some text. In the tabular, if either place or date birth is defined, I want to print the `gtrsymborn` sign followed by the place and/or date. I hope my intention becomes clear from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say the best way to do this without knowing in what other ways this data will be used in the package, especially since I am not familiar with the [genealogytree](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree) package.

With this caveat, one way to do this is to define commands, say `\DateOfBirth` and `\PlaceOfBirth`, to set the date and place of birth respectively, which could be saved in macros such as `\@dateofbirth` and `\@placeofbirth`. By setting the default values of both of these macros to `\relax` you can now test to see if either of them have been redefined by defining a new boolean, say `\ifHaveDateOrPlace`, and using something like:

```
% include the date and/or place of birth if available
\HaveDateOrPlacefalse% reset date and place boolean
\if\@dateofbirth\relax\else\HaveDateOrPlacetrue\fi
\if\@placeofbirth\relax\else\HaveDateOrPlacetrue\fi
\ifHaveDateOrPlace\gtrsymBorn \@placeofbirth \@dateofbirth \fi
```

Of course, you would also need macros to get the name of the image file and probably the persons name, but perhaps these are already provided by [genealogytree](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree). With this in place you could define a macro `\MugShot` so that the code

```
 \MugShot

 \PlaceOfBirth{Mars}
 \MugShot

 \DateOfBirth{Tuesday}
 \MugShot

 \PlaceOfBirth{Venus}
 \DateOfBirth{Wednesday}
 \MugShot
```

would produce:

[image]

(My default picture is a question mark.)

The full code for this MWE consists of the latex file:

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\begin{document}

 \MugShot

 \PlaceOfBirth{Mars}
 \MugShot

 \DateOfBirth{Tuesday}
 \MugShot

 \PlaceOfBirth{Venus}
 \DateOfBirth{Wednesday}
 \MugShot

\end{document}
```

together with the class file `myclass.cls`, which contains all of the content:

```
\LoadClass[12pt]{amsart}

\RequirePackage{genealogytree}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

% boolean to keep track of place and date of birth
\newif\ifHaveDateOrPlace
% place of birth
\providecommand\@placeofbirth{\relax}
\newcommand\PlaceOfBirth[1]{\renewcommand\@placeofbirth{\space#1}}

% date of birth
\providecommand\@dateofbirth{\relax}
\newcommand\DateOfBirth[1]{\renewcommand\@dateofbirth{\space#1}}

\providecommand\@personpicture{{\Huge?}}
\newcommand\Picture[2][]{\edef\@personpicture{\noexpand\includegraphics[width=30mm,#1]{#2}}}

% reset the people data
\newcommand\ResetData{%
\renewcommand\@placeofbirth{\relax}%
\renewcommand\@dateofbirth{\relax}%
}

\newcommand\MugShot{%
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \@personpicture\\
    % include the date and/or place of birth if available
    \HaveDateOrPlacefalse% reset date and place boolean
    \if\@dateofbirth\relax\else\HaveDateOrPlacetrue\fi
    \if\@placeofbirth\relax\else\HaveDateOrPlacetrue\fi
    \ifHaveDateOrPlace\gtrsymBorn \@placeofbirth \@dateofbirth \fi
  \end{tabular}%
  \ResetData
}

\endinput
```

If this data is only going to be used once then a better approach would probably be to define a single macro to print the photo, together with the associated data, or to use something like [pgfkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) so that you can use a key-value syntax to specify everything.